# How to scale a Corda Node horizontally?

Tags: corda

I would like to understand if it is possible to scale a Corda node out horizontally and how this would work.

I have read that the message broker is planned to be separated from the Corda node which I guess would allow for horizontal scaling. Would the message broker be the entity that is identified by the network map service or would each of the underlying Corda nodes still have their own separate network identity and vaults?

My question is for v1 open source, Corda enterprise or if it is planned for future releases.

Answer (score 0):

We have some work in progress here related to the flows and we'll talk more about this in the very near future. But in the current open source 1.0 branch it would be a scale up model.  You could scale out the Artemis MQ however.  But it would be a single node for Corda at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So just to confirm - it is not possible to run 2 Corda nodes which use the same identity certificate and have the network map point to both ip addresses? Also, how would you go about scaling out the Artemis MQ? Is it not still part of the Corda node?

Comment: No, one node equals one identity.